# x509certificate CN supported characters

Tags: x509certificate, x509

I want to know whether X509Certificate CN(commonname) support with i18n characters and which are all the supported character set

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the CN in the distinguished name of the issuer or subject of the X509 certificate in question.

[RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) on "Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile" contains a definition of the allowed value for a common name `AttributeTypeAndValue` in a distinguished name

```
-- Naming attributes of type X520CommonName:
--   X520CommonName ::= DirectoryName (SIZE (1..ub-common-name))
--
-- Expanded to avoid parameterized type:
X520CommonName ::= CHOICE {
      teletexString     TeletexString   (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)),
      printableString   PrintableString (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)),
      universalString   UniversalString (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)),
      utf8String        UTF8String      (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)),
      bmpString         BMPString       (SIZE (1..ub-common-name)) }
```

At the same time, though, it says

> CAs
> conforming to this profile MUST use either the PrintableString or
> UTF8String encoding of DirectoryString

(`DirectoryName` in the ASN.1 comment above should actually be `DirectoryString`, cf. the errata.)

There are certain exceptions to this for the sake of backward compatibility but let's consider the general case.

Thus, the common name may either be a `PrintableString` or an `UTF8String`. The former allows only to use a small subset of the characters the latter does. So you effectively are limited to what can be represented in UTF-8.

---

This does not mean, though, that you can go to a CA of your choice and insist on getting a certificate with a subject common name containing the wildest Unicode characters. CAs may have limited the set of characters they allow in the subjects of certificates they issue. This might be accidental (their software for some reason may be limited to that set), intentional to allow interoperability with other legacy software, or a deliberate security measure, e.g. to prevent misuse of similar looking Unicode characters.

Such restriction may even be documented in their CA certificates by use of name constraint extensions; in that case the CA cannot circumvent the restrictions in any way.